Next Config on images
How to setup next config to get images from http and https protocol
`/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https" || "http",
        hostname: "**",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;`

But it seems the http isn't working

that's because using || checks wether one or more of the expressions are true, since "https" is converted to true, it completely ignores the second string "http", you can do this instead:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "**",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

export default nextConfig;

